# UITableView Section Index overlapping row delete button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

After quite a lot searching around Google, Stackoverflow and apples documentation, I have almost given up.

I am making an app to index costumers and because of a potentially very long list, I use section index to navigate faster. My problem is shown in the picture below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2tTx.png]

When I drag an item to reveal the delete button, it is partially hidden below my section index bar.

I have no code setting tableview or tableviewcells width and the section index can't really be changed, as far as i am concerned.

EDIT:

The question is how I can have the tableview cells end before they get overlapped, so the delete button is fully visible.

EDIT 2:

I already tried setting the cell frame smaller without any luck.

```
cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width-30, cell.frame.size.height);
```

I also tried the same with the tableview, but as it is in a UITableViewController it cannot be resized.

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width-30, self.tableView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: So...Are you asking how the width of the section index bar can be changed? How to move the delete button so its not covered up? You kinda just state a problem, with no questions

Comment: I added a more specific question now. Is my intention more clear now?

Comment: Its possible http://i.stack.imgur.com/scNRZ.jpg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a simple work-around we resolved the visual overlap of the index by setting the background color of the index to clearColor.

```
self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

* This looks visually better, but the index will still overlap your tableViewCell.

Another possible work-around would be to hide the index bar when entering edit mode:

```
// allow editing
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
// hides the index
self.tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = NSIntegerMax;
```

Comment: Created a bug report for Apple. Until it is fixed, this must do.

Comment: Just add the code conditionally for iOS 7 only. A quick SO search will turn up multiple ways to detect iOS version.

Answer (score 6):

The `inEditMode` method should do the trick. Below I embed a complete code that hides the index while editing and shows it again when the editing is done.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self inEditMode:YES];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self inEditMode:NO];
}
//on self.editButtonItem click
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self inEditMode:editing];
}

-(void)inEditMode:(BOOL)inEditMode{
    if (inEditMode) { //hide index while in edit mode
        self.tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = NSIntegerMax;
    }else{
         self.tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = NSIntegerMin;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this code before allocating any subview in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
for (id object in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    [object removeFromSuperview];
}
```